# Figure in columns in itemize

Tags: beamer, itemize, columns

I`m trying to make an itemized list, where only one of the items has an image to the right.
I tried this

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Dresden}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Problem}
  \begin{itemize}
     \item 
     \begin{columns}
        \column{.7\linewidth}
        Here I want some text with an image to the right, all in the same item
        \column{.3\linewidth}
        \rule{.2\linewidth}{.2\linewidth}
     \end{columns}
     \item Some more text here that is long enough to continue bellow the image
 \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

But this is what I get instead

[image: columns not inside item]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `columns` only for first item and close it before the second item.

Next code shows the solution. I has a little problem, `columns` don't use the complete `\linewidth`, first one is `.65\linewidth` and second `.25\linewidth` in order to align first and second item symbols. I think I've read something about this problem somewhere but I don't remember where now. If I find it I'll explain the solution.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Dresden}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Solution}
        \begin{columns}
            \column{.65\linewidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Here I want some text with an image to the right, all in the same item
            \end{itemize}
            \column{.25\linewidth}
            \rule{.2\linewidth}{.2\linewidth}
        \end{columns}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Some more text here that is long enough to continue bellow the image
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Update*

The reference I was looking for is [provide more usable columns environment](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/262), an issue discussion in [beamer's github place](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer).

My conclusion is: it's safer to use `totalwidth` option to columns environment if you want to avoid problems with intercolumns spaces and margins. And more important: don't confuse `\linewidth` with `\textwidth` as I did in previous example.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Dresden}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Solution}
        \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth] %<---
            \column{.7\textwidth} %<---
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Here I want some text with an image to the right, all in the same item
            \end{itemize}
            \column{.3\textwidth} %<---
            \rule{.2\linewidth}{.2\linewidth}
        \end{columns}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Some more text here that is long enough to continue bellow the image
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `minipage`s too:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Dresden}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Problem}
  \begin{itemize}
     \item
     \begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\linewidth}
        Here I want some text with an image to the right, all in the same item
     \end{minipage}%
     \begin{minipage}{.3\linewidth}
        \centering
        \rule{.2\linewidth}{.2\linewidth}
     \end{minipage}
     \item Some more text here that is long enough to continue bellow the image
 \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `%` sign after the first minipage is of utmost importance! Why is that?!?!